# Xcode doesn't show titles for all windows in the mission control view (4 fingers swipe down)

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion

Mac Mission Control (4 fingers swipe down) is a handy feature which allows us to navigate different windows of one application.

Most applications would show the window titles underneath each window thumbnail, so it's easy to find the window you want to bring to the front.

However if I open a few projects in Xcode 4.2.1 and do 4-finger-swipe-down, I can't see any "titles" or "project names" underneath the window thumbnails. This is annoying as sometimes the window preview thumbnails are not always big enough to recognize whats inside.

Is there any setting I need to change to make it displayed? Or it is not possible yet?

> **Edited on 28/Jan/2012**: I got the reply from Apple Bug Report:
>
> 18-Jan-2012 08:07 AM Apple Developer Bug Reporting Team :
>   This bug has been closed as Duplicate. We are aware of this issue and are tracking it under the Bug ID 10044627
>
> **Edited on 27/Feb/2012:**
>   This is confirmed solved in Xcode 4.3

Comment: perhaps a visit to bug reporter is in order

Comment: This is confirmed solved in Xcode 4.3

Comment: this is an old issue that is basically just a bug report to apple, voting to close

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Xcode 4.6.2 and this issue should be resolved